# json_decode returns string type instead of object

Tags: php, json

I'm passing a JSON-encoded string to `json_decode()` and am expecting its output to be an object type, but am getting a string type instead.  How can I return an object?

In the docs, the following returns an object:

```
$json = '{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}';
var_dump(json_decode($json));
```

However, if I `json_encode()` the string first and then call `json_decode()`, the output is a string and not an object:

```
$json = json_encode('{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}');
var_dump(json_decode($json));
```

This is just a simplified example. In practice what I'm doing is pushing a JSON-encoded string to PHP via AJAX.  However it does illustrate the problem of converting this encoded JSON string to an object I can read in PHP, e.g., "`$json->a`".

How can I return an object type?

thanks for the replies !
 The actual context for this question was am using a JSON Response from a API.
 But when I do the json_decode to this response and try to access the values like - $json=json_decode(json response from API); 
echo $json->a 
it gives me a error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

Comment: Why do you want to encode an already encoded JSON ? EX : `$json = json_encode('{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}');` ?

Comment: You're encoding a string, not an object so obviously you'll get a string when you decode it.

Comment: absolutely right musa.! if you are passing an string than how could you expect for object?

Comment: thanks, understood the problem specific to the examples given by me.

Answer (score 7):

The function `json_encode` is used to encode a native PHP object or array in JSON format.

For example, `$json = json_encode($arr)` where `$arr` is

```
$arr = array(
  'a' => 1,
  'b' => 2,
  'c' => 3,
  'd' => 4,
  'e' => 5,
);
```

would return the string `$json = '{"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3, "d": 4, "e": 5}'`. At this point, you do **not** need to encode it again with `json_encode`!

To obtain your array back, simply do `json_decode($json, true)`.

If you omit the `true` from the call to `json_decode` you'll obtain an instance of `stdClass` instead, with the various properties specified in the JSON string.

For more references, see:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: thanks for the replies ! The actual context for this question was am using a JSON Response from a API. But when I do the json_decode to this response and try to access the values like - $json=json_decode(json response from API); echo $json->a it gives me a error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

Comment: I see.. could you show us the actual json response you're working with?

Comment: got d problem ! it was getting double json_decoded so var_dump was giving string instead of object.

Answer (score 1):

```
var_dump(json_decode($json, true));
```

http://hk.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: checked through var_dump function and debugged. thanks for reminding this function :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of writing on the JSON array, try putting it into a PHP array first.

```
<?php
$array = array(
'a' => 1,
'b' => 2,
'c' => 3,
'd' => 4,
'e' => 5
);
//Then json_encode()
$json = json_encode($array);
echo $json;
die;
?>
```

In you case, you are using ajax. So when you get a success, you can do this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'example.com',
    data: {

    },
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Where after data inside console.log() can add the json var like data.a, data.b...

Also, with the string you providedm you do not need to json_encode since it is alrady in json format

Answer (score 0):

in your question you confused **json_encode** with and **json_decode**:

```
$json = json_encode('{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}');
var_dump(json_decode($json));
```

its should be:

```
$json = json_decode('{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}');
var_dump(json_encode($json));
```