# Retrieve Json Decode Elements

Tags: php, json

I've tried a variety of things, but still have not been able to return username from the output below. How would I do this? I ran this line below and got the string below:

```
$work = exec($cmd);
var_dump($work);
$json_object = json_decode($work, true);




string(1118) "{"user"=>{"id"=>4151878, "username"=>"jerry_smithjerry", "firstname"=>"Jerry ", "lastname"=>"Smith", "birthday"=>nil, "sex"=>0, "city"=>nil, "state"=>nil, "country"=>nil, "registration_date"=>"2013-07-24T16:12:20-04:00", "about"=>"", "domain"=>"jerry_smithjerry.500px.com", "fotomoto_on"=>false, "locale"=>"en", "show_nude"=>false, "fullname"=>"Jerry Smith", "userpic_url"=>"/graphics/userpic.png", "upgrade_status"=>0, "store_on"=>false, "email"=>"jerry_smithjerry@aol.com", "upload_limit"=>20, "upload_limit_expiry"=>"2013-07-24T21:50:58-04:00", "upgrade_type"=>0, "upgrade_status_expiry"=>nil, "auth"=>{"facebook"=>0, "twitter"=>0}, "contacts"=>{}, "equipment"=>{}, "photos_count"=>0, "affection"=>0, "in_favorites_count"=>0, "friends_count"=>0, "followers_count"=>0, "not_active"=>true, "avatars"=>{"default"=>{"http"=>"/graphics/userpic.png", "https"=>"/graphics/userpic.png"}, "large"=>{"http"=>"/graphics/userpic.png", "https"=>"/graphics/userpic.png"}, "small"=>{"http"=>"/graphics/userpic.png", "https"=>"/graphics/userpic.png"}, "tiny"=>{"http"=>"/graphics/userpic.png", "https"=>"/graphics/userpic.png"}}}}" "
```

echo:

```
{"user"=>{"id"=>4151878, "username"=>"jerry_smithjerry", "firstname"=>"Jerry ", "lastname"=>"Smith", "birthday"=>nil, "sex"=>0, "city"=>nil, "state"=>nil, "country"=>nil, "registration_date"=>"2013-07-24T16:12:20-04:00", "about"=>"", "domain"=>"jerry_smithjerry.500px.com", "fotomoto_on"=>false, "locale"=>"en", "show_nude"=>false, "fullname"=>"Jerry Smith", "userpic_url"=>"/graphics/userpic.png", "upgrade_status"=>0, "store_on"=>false, "email"=>"jerry_smithjerry@aol.com", "upload_limit"=>20, "upload_limit_expiry"=>"2013-07-24T22:11:09-04:00", "upgrade_type"=>0, "upgrade_status_expiry"=>nil, "auth"=>{"facebook"=>0, "twitter"=>0}, "contacts"=>{}, "equipment"=>{}, "photos_count"=>0, "affection"=>0, "in_favorites_count"=>0, "friends_count"=>0, "followers_count"=>0, "not_active"=>true, "avatars"=>{"default"=>{"http"=>"/graphics/userpic.png", "https"=>"/graphics/userpic.png"}, "large"=>{"http"=>"/graphics/userpic.png", "https"=>"/graphics/userpic.png"}, "small"=>{"http"=>"/graphics/userpic.png", "https"=>"/graphics/userpic.png"}, "tiny"=>{"http"=>"/graphics/userpic.png", "https"=>"/graphics/userpic.png"}}}}
```

var_dump:

```
string(1118) "{"user"=>{"id"=>4151878, "username"=>"jerry_smithjerry", "firstname"=>"Jerry ", "lastname"=>"Smith", "birthday"=>nil, "sex"=>0, "city"=>nil, "state"=>nil, "country"=>nil, "registration_date"=>"2013-07-24T16:12:20-04:00", "about"=>"", "domain"=>"jerry_smithjerry.500px.com", "fotomoto_on"=>false, "locale"=>"en", "show_nude"=>false, "fullname"=>"Jerry Smith", "userpic_url"=>"/graphics/userpic.png", "upgrade_status"=>0, "store_on"=>false, "email"=>"jerry_smithjerry@aol.com", "upload_limit"=>20, "upload_limit_expiry"=>"2013-07-24T22:11:09-04:00", "upgrade_type"=>0, "upgrade_status_expiry"=>nil, "auth"=>{"facebook"=>0, "twitter"=>0}, "contacts"=>{}, "equipment"=>{}, "photos_count"=>0, "affection"=>0, "in_favorites_count"=>0, "friends_count"=>0, "followers_count"=>0, "not_active"=>true, "avatars"=>{"default"=>{"http"=>"/graphics/userpic.png", "https"=>"/graphics/userpic.png"}, "large"=>{"http"=>"/graphics/userpic.png", "https"=>"/graphics/userpic.png"}, "small"=>{"http"=>"/graphics/userpic.png", "https"=>"/graphics/userpic.png"}, "tiny"=>{"http"=>"/graphics/userpic.png", "https"=>"/graphics/userpic.png"}}}}"
```

Comment: try `var_dump($work)`

Comment: @DevZer0 I only want to store the value of username as a variable.

Comment: i understand but your json_decode returns a string, so can u run a `var_dump($work)` before you json_decode and show the output

Comment: @user2600095 echo or var_dump the value of $work. it's odd that its returning a string.

Comment: @kennypu, When I echo, it does not return a string. When I var_dump, it returns a string.

Comment: Can you show us what it returns please

Comment: @user2600095 the edit is the same thing as what you have originally. post the result of DevZer0's first comment.

Comment: @user2600095 next question is: what's the value of `exec($cmd)`?

Comment: @kennypu What do you mean by this? I set $work = exec($cmd). It's a variable. I then perform the commands above.

Comment: @user2600095 assuming `exec($cmd);` returns a valid JSON string, the above code should work

Comment: @kennypu I'm confused. What code are talking about to return username?

Comment: @user2600095 in the above example, if you var_dump($json_object), what do you get

Comment: @kennypu, It returns a very long string, with several variables. How would I only return username? I'm confused.

Comment: @user2600095 what type is it? is it still a string type? or object/array.

Comment: @kennypu, I'm really confused. Please see my post. When I var_dump it's a string. When I echo, it is not. See above.

Comment: @user2600095 the echo is still a string. only var_dump tells you what the variable type is. You may want to learn more on json/php if you're that confused.

Comment: @kennypu I'm confused what command will get the username from the string. You keep mentioning this. What command? I understand it's a string.

Comment: json is a string. when you run `json_decode()` it's suppose to convert it into a Object or Array, not a string. From there, you just access the username variable. You cannot (not easily) access the username variable if you're trying to get it from a string. In your example above, $json_object['user']['username'] SHOULD give you the username.

Comment: @kennypu I undertand. $json_object['user']['username'] does not return anything though!

Comment: @user2600095 right, because in your case $json_object is a string, not an array. Which means that whatever `exec($cmd)` is, it is probably not a valid json string. which is why I asked to show the value of that. a valid json format is: '{"key": "value", "another_key" : "value"}' if the result of `exec($cmd)` is not like that, there is your problem.

Comment: @kennypu, exec($cmd) is not like that. So how would I return the value of username?

Answer (score 0):

Your json string doesn't have valid json, the `json` strings uses `:` as a key value separator, in your case you have used a php associative array like `=>` notation. This json is not valid json,

Comment: ok what should I do then? That's probably why I haven't got this to work.

Comment: this isn't the answer. If you try the string he gave, it will return NULL not a string.

Comment: @kennypu I'm confused. What command are you talking about running?

Comment: @user2600095 look at my answer. Edit your post to show where you set $work.

Answer (score -1):

according to this: [json_decode returns string type instead of object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12210084/json-decode-returns-string-type-instead-of-object) You may be running `json_encode()` on a json string. `json_encode()` is used if you want to turn an object or array into json.

If you are doing something like `$work = json_encode($json_string)` somewhere before that code, that would be the cause. remove that line, run `json_decode()` on your original json string and it should be fine.

Once you flesh that out, you can do

```
$json_object = json_decode($your_json_string); 
echo $json_object->user->username; //echo's the username
```

Comment: @DevZer0 ahh, I wonder how that happened? it shouldn't be possible as json_decode returns either an object, array, or null if it's not valid json.

Comment: @kennypu thats why i keep telling  OP to show the var_dump of `$work`

Comment: @DevZer0 I'm assuming my edited answer is the reason why it's returning a string.